# 3D RGB plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a 3-by-4 matrix in which each column has the 3 components R, G and B of a particular color. I need to plot each component in a 3D plot as a single point and, if possible, paint each of the points with the color of the RGB components that correspond to it.

I have tried with the `plot3` function, but it paints a continuous line, and it has only one color.

For example, this is my matrix:

```
centroids = 

47    85   104   126   
37    66    86   103   
36    55    71    90
```

where `(47,37,36)` are the RGB coordinates of the first point, therefore I need to plot it as a single point in the RGB space and with this particular color. My idea was to have a for loop like this:

```
for i = 1:4
    plot3( centroids(1,i),centroids(2,i),centroids(3,i),'Color',centroids(:,i))
end
```

But it gives me an error, and it I do not try to change the color, it paints only a line and with the same color. Is there a way to plot each column of the matrix as an independent point and with the color of the RGB components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [`scatter3`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html?searchHighlight=scatter3) function instead. Here is a sample with your data, assuming it is contained in an array called `A`:

```
scatter3(A(1,:), A(2,:), A(3,:), 50, (A/255)', 'filled')
```

and the result:

[image: Result]

Best,

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks! Is there a way to make the points bigger? I am quite new at Matlab coding, sorry for my inexperience!

Comment: Sure, to change the markers' size you can vary the 4th parameter of `scatter3`, which is more or less the area of the markers in pixels. See the documentation for more details.